# Javascript setTimeout handle promise rejection

Tags: javascript

Im currently trying to make a timeout for a function

```
setTimeout(() => function_name(), 10000)
```

This function may raise an exception or reject a promise

How do I handle a rejection in this case ?

Im unsure of what to try

Comment: Exceptions work exactly the same inside a function whether it's invoked directly or invoked via `setTimeout`, and there is no promise anywhere in your code to be rejected, so we really have no idea what your question is. Please add enough code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a try/catch

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  try {
    function_name();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}, 10000);
```